# Using Asynchronous Logging With Log4J2 in Spark Scala Application

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, sbt, spark-streaming, log4j2

The Issue: I am unable to observe the asynchronous capabilities of Log4J2 after initializing SparkContext in Spark local mode.

Log4j2 dependencies in SBT:

```
  "com.lmax" % "disruptor" % "3.3.5",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.8.2",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.8.2",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" %% "log4j-api-scala" % "2.8.2"
```

Log4j2 config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <File name="File-Appender" fileName="logs/xmlfilelog.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger  name="guru.springframework.blog.log4j2async" level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="File-Appender"/>he preceding c
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I set the following system property in IntelliJ

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
```

To test asynchronous behavior, I ran the following code snippet before and after initializing SparkContext:

```
val start = System.nanoTime()

for(i <- 1 to 1000) {
  logger.error("Hello")
}

val end = System.nanoTime()
val timeMS = (end - start)/1000000
println(s"Parsed ${iterations} reports in ${timeMS} ms ${timeMS/1000} sec")
```

Successful result: I was able to see the following debug line confirming AsyncContext was enabled `2017-04-25 14:55:40,541 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=AsyncContext@6d9c638, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@758f4f03] started OK.`.  Additionally, my print line statement, "Parsed..." displayed somewhere in the middle of the logger output, indicating async behavior.

However, once I moved this code block after the SparkContext initialization, I no longer observer async activity.  The print line statement, "Parsed..." always displays after the logger output.  What is confusing is that `2017-04-25 14:55:40,541 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=AsyncContext@6d9c638, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@758f4f03] started OK.`. is still observed.

For a sanity check, I also printed the package of the logger api inside the scope of the spark application.  The result yielded `package org.apache.logging.log4j.scala, Apache Log4j Scala 2.11 wrapper for Log4j API, version 2.8.2`.  According to the Log4J2 docs, "og4j 2 Scala API is dependent on the Log4j 2 API."  Thus, I believe I can deduce that I am actually using Log4J2.

MAIN QUESTION: IS SPARK SOMEHOW INTERCEPTING MY LOG4J2 CONFIGURATION AND DEFAULTING TO ITS LOG4J CONFIGURATION, OR DOES IT NOT ALLOW ASYNC LOGGING BEHAVIOR?

Comment: It's an old post so just wanted to mention that I tested it locally and it didn't reproduce. Spark 2.4.5 and log4j 2.17.0. Async seems to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you should make sure is that the system property is set *before* Log4j2 is initialized.

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
```

It seems to me that this is done correctly: If you can see that an `AsyncLoggerContext` is used then you can be sure you are using Disruptor-backed Async Loggers.

Comment: Yes, it appears `AsyncLoggerContext` is used even in the executors.  I see the lines `2017-04-26 10:11:15,660 Executor task launch worker-7 DEBUG LoggerContext[name=DefaultAsyncContext@Executor task launch worker-6, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@56465954] started OK.
10:11:15.662 [Executor task launch worker-7] ERROR LoggingTestWithRDD - Hello`.  However, async behavior is not occurring.  Perhaps it has something to do with Spark local mode..

Comment: The problem is likely in how you are trying to verify async behavior. Try a simpler print statement `println("This is System.out.println")` (without string interpolation), and increase the number of iterations in the `for` loop to 10K or 50K.

Comment: That is a bit odd indeed. Have you tried asking on the Spark mailing list?

Comment: Just posted to the mailing list